# devices don't support framework version

Tags: android, kotlin

I get an error when trying to upload my apk to google playstore

```
Doesn't support framework version (1562 devices)
safe: "21 and onwards"
```

What does that mean? Here is my build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sumizeit.sumizeit"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 12
    versionName "12"
    multiDexEnabled true  //ADD THIS LINE
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Comment: did you update any library? it usually happens when you update a library that has a minSdk requirement

Comment: Did you figure out the problem? I'm having the same problem myself

Comment: @TheGix ,
 Chris Did you figure out ?

Answer (score -1):

minSdkVersion 21
change it to
minSdkVersion 16 and that might solve it

compileSdkVersion 29
defaultConfig {
applicationId "xxxxx.xxxxxx"
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 29
versionCode 10
versionName "10"
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}